# Cannot understand regex with brackets

Tags: regex, text, grep

How to grep by regexp for files with `helloworld(...)` when it only contains rows with '.get' extension?

```
a(text)

b(text)

helloworld(
text.get
text.get
text.get
text.get
)
c(text)
```

Then, example like this:

```
a(text)

b(text)

helloworld(
text.pass
text.pass
text.pass
text.pass
)
c(text)
```

shouldn't be found

I tried regexp `[a-z_]+\.get`, but it helps to find files with extension, but I don't know how to wrap it with `helloworld(` and end with `)`

Comment: `grep` matches line by line. You can't match multiline

Comment: It depends. I want to find files containing helloworld and .get. I think it's not important to have multiline support. What do you think?

Comment: To print the names of files that contain helloworld and .get would be `awk '/helloworld/{a=1} /\.get/{b=1} END{if (a&&b) print FILENAME}' *`. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have gnu grep then you can use `-z` option to treat while file as sequence of lines and use this command to list matching blocks:

```
grep -zoP 'helloworld\s*\(\s*(\w+\.get\b\s*)+\)\s*' file
```

To list all matching files in a directory use:

```
grep -zPl 'helloworld\s*\(\s*(\w+\.get\b\s*)+\)\s*' file*
```

Answer (score 1):

AKAIK `grep` works one line at a time.

This perl one-liner does what you want:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print $& if /helloworld\(\R(?:[a-z_]+\.get\R)+\)/' file
```

**Result for first file:**

```
helloworld(
text.get
text.get
text.get
text.get
)
```

**Result for second file:**

```
NOTHING
```

Comment: I have never touched perl :( Does it possible to implement this for a directory and count results like `wc -l' do?